Как удалить вторую английскую раскладку клавиатуры?
Вопрос таков: как удалить 2ю английскую интернациональную раскладку клавиатуры? в настройках язык и регион в параметрах её нету :(


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Вот как можно удалить вторую раскладку клавиатуры в Windows 11:

В Windows 11 нажмите по индикатору языка в области уведомлений и выберите «Дополнительные настройки клавиатуры», либо перейдите в Параметры — Время и язык — Язык и регион.



В Windows 11 справа от языка, который нужно удалить, нажмите по трем точкам и выберите пункт «Удалить». Если пункт не активен, сначала переместите язык вниз (первый по счету язык удалить нельзя).


Подробней можно посмотреть тут
